# How to apply CSS to some selected coordinates of div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on `React.js` project to render the pdf and highlight some text. I have coordinates and text.
I tried `react-pdf-highlighter` 
 [image]

I want to highlight part of the given coordinates.
I am using `react-pdf` to render the pdf

Comment: Which part do you want to highlight?

Comment: @Mikkel box show that coordinates I want to highlight only coordinates inside the div

Comment: So you could render a colored box with some kind of opacity, which would effectively highlight the text? Or draw a box behind the text?

Comment: I want to add background color inside the box